# Can't set second monitor to full resolution in kubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors

I just installed Ubuntu Server 11.04, and `kubuntu-desktop`. I have a Intel i3 processor, and an Intel DH67CL Mainboard and am using the onboard graphics card.

I have two monitors:

- One is connected to the HDMI port and has a max res. of 1680x1050
- Other connected to the DVI with a max res of 1920x1080

The first one, I am using as my master monitor and it detects and runs at that resolution.
the second one, I can only set it to 1024x768.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It could be an EDID related problem. Try this:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=316985

Instead of the app mentioned on the post use read-edid available from the Ubuntu repositories:

```
# apt-get read-edid
```

and then

```
get-edid > file.raw
```

Comment: i tried, but i can't seem to run the program with wine...

Comment: You're right. Try using the new app I've added to the post.

Comment: Thanx, but i'm still having problems: i don't have a /etc/x11 folder... could this be because my graphics card is Intel and not nVidia?

Comment: You should, it's a standard folder since I can remember.

Comment: yes, you're right, i was trying lower case x11, it's X11. Anyways, it didn't work...